# MongoError: failed to connect to server [<docker-machine>:<port>] on first connect

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose, replicaset

Trying to connect MongoDB with replicaSet connection string using mongoose library. But didn't connect on the production server, its throw me back an error:

```
name: 'MongoError',
 message: 'failed to connect to server [test-machine:27018] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND test-machine:27018 test-machine:27018]'
```

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose') //version 4.13.6

var options = { "db": {
        "readPreference": "secondaryPreferred"
    },
    "replset": {
        "rs_name": "testReplica",
    }
}

var connection = mongoose.createConnection(`mongodb://localhost:27018/`,options);

connection.on('open', function () {
    console.log('We are connected')
})

connection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Something went wrong')
    console.log(err)
})
```

Note: the above code working fine with a success message in/with my local machine.

Comment: Default port is 27017 maybe try that? Also you may need to include your database's name at the end of its URL

Comment: @molamk my mongo-docker run on 27018 port and I have tried with database name too. but its still throw the same error.

Comment: you may want to add the `docker` tag to your question. And also the `Dockerfile` and relevant configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **DNS** resolution error.

added test-machine to my /etc/hosts file